# Why is supabase count query much slower than select *?

Tags: postgresql, supabase

When I execute a count query using supabase's syntax, `.select("*", { count: "exact", head: true })`, it's significantly slower than a `select("*")` query. It's also significantly slower than if I just run the query in the Supabase query UI, i.e. "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...". Why is that? Is there someway to speed it up? I've tried using `estimated` or `planned` settings for `count` but there's no noticeable speed increase. I notice in the Chrome network inspector it doesn't actually modify the query it's sending. Screenshots from the network tab are below.

Queries in chrome, first is select *, second is count:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6H12.png)

First query payload:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYSRN.png)

Second query payload:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYWz0.png)

This is even the case for queries that return thousands of results. I'm trying to use the count query for pagination purposes in a search result table but given the slowness of the count query I'm actually finding it more efficient to just query for the full set of results without a limit and do the pagination on the front end which doesn't feel right...

TLDR: Querying for count, expected it to be much faster than fetching all the results, it was much slower instead

Comment: From here [JS Select](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select): *Count algorithm to use to count rows in the table or view. `"exact"`: Exact but slow count algorithm. Performs a `COUNT(*)` under the hood. `"planned"`: Approximated but fast count algorithm. Uses the Postgres statistics under the hood. `"estimated"`: Uses exact count for low numbers and planned count for high numbers.* . As to why `COUNT` is slow  in Postgres see [Count](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks but I tried those other settings and they didn't help. I just updated my question to mention that. Also, I wouldn't think even a `COUNT(*)` would be slow in my case since my DB only has ~200k records.

Comment: Then crank up the logging on the database and see what is actually hitting the database. I suspect this is an issue for the supabase developers.

Comment: Thanks yeah I'm wondering if it's an underlying supabase issue

Comment: Could you provide actual numbers for everything? How many rows do you have in your table? How long does it take for the SQL and your supabase-js request?

Comment: @dshukertjr There are about 250,000 rows. Not sure about how long it takes. I can try to check again. Thanks